# mysql query returns values outside of WHERE range when using BETWEEN or >= & <=

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm stumped.  I have a date field in a MySQL database that I fill from a csv file.  The date field is in a format of mdy, so it can have leading zeros (which I thought was the problem).  So Aug 9, 2015 would be 080915 in the CSV file, but in the database it comes in as 80915.  This field is an INT(6)

So I have a query:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt = 080915;
```

This WORKS perfectly.
My database doesn't include any data prior to 010115.
So if I use:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt = 080914;
```

I get no result, which is CORRECT.
However, if I use:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt <= 080914;
```

I get all the data from 010115 to 080915..
And if I use a range like:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt >= 080915 AND invdt <= 083115;
```

I get the correct data in that range, but if I use:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt >= 080914 AND invdt <= 083114;
```

I get all the same data as if the date range was for 2015, even though the dates are 2014.  It SHOULD just return nothing since that data doesn't exist.

So I tried changing the field to a VARCHAR instead of an INT, thinking the leading zeros were throwing it off.
I loaded the data from the CSV file and looked at it and it is now showing 080915 for the entry (has the leading zeros).
I wasn't sure if the varchar would work in a greater than and less than capacity, but it seems to work fine, as long as the data exists.  If it doesn't, it still returns values, just as it did when the field was an INT value.

If I use WHERE invdt = 080915 I get a result as I should, and if I use WHERE invdt = 080914 I get no result (which I should).  I can do it with and without quotes and I still get the right result.  As soon as I try to use BETWEEN or a <= and >= or any combination of that, I get data outside the date range I am specifying if the dates don't exist in the database.
So this query:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt >= 080915 AND invdt <= 083115;
```

returns the exact same data as:

```
SELECT sum(amt) as sum_amt FROM invoices WHERE invdt >= 080914 AND invdt <= 083114;
```

???

It's acting like 080914 is the same as 080915 regardless of whether the field is a INT or VARCHAR.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Please explain what `invdt >= 080915` is supposed to be doing.  The column name suggests that it is a date.  Yet, you are comparing it to the number 80,915.  That doesn't make sense to me.  After all, you should be storing dates using a database format, such as `date`.

Comment: I figured it would be something easy.. I keep thinking of this as a date field because usually the old CISAM database I pull it out of works like a date.. once I moved it to SQL it's not a date any more.. Sometimes you just don't see what is right in front of you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing dates you are comparing int(6)'s.
If you are was going to compare dates stored at integers then it would make more sense to store them as most significant digit first as yymmdd. 
The difference between 083115 and 080314 is only 1, which is a year.
If you think about it as how they would sort from smallest to largest and what they represent I think it will make sense.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I figured out how to change my LOAD DATA INFILE to convert the mdy to a real date field.

Comment: Just my opinion, but if the integer were rearranged as most significant digit first YYMMDD, there would be no reason to convert to a date. If you intend on using that field as a date, i.e. computing difference with some other date, displaying in a nice format etc then by all means convert to a date.  I sort of follow the 'run with what ya brung' thinking. Converting all the int(6)'s to dates could be 'expensive' YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a date format of `MMDDYY`.  As you have said, these are integers which represent dates.

But, they represent dates poorly. Why?  Unquestionably August 16, 2015 is after August 17, 2014.  But the integer 081615 is *smaller* than 081714. So your date range comparisons are all fouled up.

If you can change the `invdt` column in your table to the `DATE` datatype, you should do so.  Create a new column called invdt in the table,

```
ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN invdate DATE
```

then issue this UPDATE. It uses [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to [format your date information correctly.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
 UPDATE invoices SET invdate = STR_TO_DATE(invdt, '%m%d%y')
```

Then you can issue SELECT queries like

```
SELECT SUM(amt) as sum_amt 
  FROM invoices
  WHERE invdate >= '2015-08-31'
    AND invdate <= '2015-09-08'
```

You can even do cool date arithmetic. For example this makes a daily summary of invoices for the most recent two weeks.

```
 SELECT SUM(amt) as sum_amt,
        invdate
   FROM invoices
  WHERE invdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
    AND invdate < CURDATE()
  GROUP BY invdate
```

If you *can't* change your table, then you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` like this.

```
SELECT SUM(amt) as sum_amt 
  FROM invoices
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(invdt,'%m%d%y') >= '2015-08-31'
    AND STR_TO_DATE(invdt,'%m%d%y') <= '2015-09-08'
```

Comment: Thanks.  What I ended up doing was when I load my CSV file I loaded the value (which was formatted like 080915) into @invdt then in the same SQL statement I set invdt = str_to_date(@invdt, '%m%d%y').  Then I set the field to be a date on the table, and when I loaded the data again it came in as a proper date field with each number where it belongs.  Then I just had to go back into all my different PHP functions and change the date variables to match that format and everything works right now.